# Haskell - Overwriting parameters causes unexpected behaviours

Tags: haskell, parameters

I wrote a simple function

```
someFunc list elem = do
    list <- elem:elem:elem:list
    return elem
```

Now, when i'm using it, i'm getting output like this

```
*Main> someFunc [] 'a'
"aaa"
```

Despite the fact, that this function has no practical use, why does it happen? Why does editing list have any effect in `elem`? And how to assign new value to `list` avoiding this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Note that your function will be de-sugared into this:

```
someFunc :: [b] -> b -> [b]
someFunc list elem = (elem:elem:elem:list) >>= \list -> return elem
```

Now note that the `list` in `\list -> return elem` is different from the input `list` you pass to the function.

Now see how the Monad instance for list is defined:

```
instance Monad [] where  
    return x = [x]  
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)  
    fail _ = []
```

So, your code is translated to this form finally:

```
someFunc list elem = concat $ map (\list -> return elem) (elem:elem:elem:list)
```

Now can you understand why you are getting that output ?

`someFunc [] 'a'` will get be applied like this:

```
concat $ map (\list -> return 'a') ('a':'a':'a':[])
concat $ [['a'],['a'],['a']]
'a':'a':'a':[]
"aaa"
```

Comment: The desugaring goes `someFunc list elem = (elem:elem:elem:list) >>= (\list -> return elem)` ; no new vairable `x` is introduced by the desugaring.

Comment: @GPhilip Thanks, updated. I initially kept that as `x` to make sure that OP understands that is not the same `list` as the input value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a new value to `list`, what's happening is the `list` on the left of the `<-` is different than the `list` on the right of the `<-`.  If you turn on warnings with `-Wall` you'll see

```
<interactive>:13:19: Warning:
    This binding for `elem' shadows the existing binding
      imported from `Prelude' (and originally defined in `GHC.List')

<interactive>:14:7: Warning:
    This binding for `list' shadows the existing binding
      bound at <interactive>:13:14

<interactive>:14:7: Warning: Defined but not used: `list'
```

You aren't using the name `list` defined by `list <- ...`, just defining it so that it happens to shadow the existing binding.

The reason `someFunc [] 'a'` returns `"aaa"` is due to how the list monad works.  This do notation would be equivalent to

```
someFunc list e = (e:e:e:list) >>= \l -> return e
```

And for lists, `>>=` is essentially `concatMap`, so you have

```
someFunc list e = concatMap (\l -> return e) (e:e:e:list)
```

So substituting in `[]` for `list` and `'a'` for `e` we get

```
someFunc [] 'a' = concatMap (\l -> return 'a') "aaa"
                = concat $ map (\l -> return 'a') "aaa"
                = concat [['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
                = ['a', 'a', 'a']
                = "aaa"
```

Your confusion probably comes from the use of `return`.  In most languages `return` is a keyword, but in Haskell it's just a function.  It does not exit a function call early, all it does is wrap a value in the context of the monad you're in.  For lists `return x = [x]`, that's the entire definition.  Additionally, in Haskell you can't reassign values, but you can shadow them with a new definition.  If you always compile with `-Wall` and `-Werror` though, you'll keep yourself from having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are (apparently accidentally) using the list monad. In Python, your snippet would be expressed as:

```
for list in [elem, elem, elem] + list:
    yield elem
```

That is, you create a list containing one `elem` for each item in the list, plus three more.

Here's what you probably intended:

```
someFunc list elem = do
    list <- return (elem:elem:elem:list)
    return elem
```

This just creates a new `list` variable shadowing your old one, and completely ignores it to return `elem`.